# In Pytorch, if I have a 2D tensor, how to iterate over this tensor to get every value changed

Tags: pytorch

I have a 2d Tensor, whose size is 1024x1024 and the values in the tensor is 0.3333, 0.6667, and 1.0000, so I would like to change all these values to 0,1,2.

Could some one tell me how to iterate over this tensor.

Comment: Hi, I just do a trick, `torch.round(tensor_a / 0.3).long()-1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the original tensor is $x$.

```
x = torch.tensor([[0.3333, 0.6667, 1.0000], [1.0000, 0.6667, 0.3333]])
```

produces

```
x

tensor([[ 0.3333,  0.6667,  1.0000],
        [ 1.0000,  0.6667,  0.3333]])
```

We can do a broadcasting and then cast it to an integer tensor

```
y = (3 * x - 1).int()
y

tensor([[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 2,  1,  0]], dtype=torch.int32

)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
t1 = torch.tensor([[0.33, 1.], [0.66, 1.]])
t1_t = (t1 == 0.66 ) + ((t1 == 0.33 ) * 0) + ((t1 == 1. ) * 2)
```